# Combinar arrays

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, array

Bom, tentarei explicar um pouco melhor conforme pediram.

Possuo 3 `arrays` simples, estou usando um exemplo com 3 `arrays`, mas na verdade o número de `arrays` não é definido, pois eles são montados a partir de escolhas do usuário, então posso ter de 2 a 5 arrays dependendo do que o usuário escolher. Mas na maioria seria 3 `arrays`:
(Diminui o tamanho do `array` para ficar de mais fácil compreensão)

```
[A,B]
[1,2]
[x,y]
```

E preciso fazer uma combinação entre eles para que saia algo como:

```
[A,1,x]
[A,1,y]
[A,2,x]
[A,2,y]
[B,1,x]
[B,1,y]
[B,2,x]
[B,2,y]
```

A saída deve ser um novo `array` com a relação entre todos os valores dos anteriores. Seria melhor se pudesse ser feito em `JS` mas pode ser por `PHP` também.

Comment: Nao esta muito claro qual e a regra de combinacao Fleuquer, pode nos descrever?

Comment: E você quer em JS ou PHP?

Comment: Fiz algumas correções para explicar melhor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fazendo uma solução ao estilo da do @Vinicius, mas utilizando sintaxe de ES6 ficaria bem mais compacto. Para isso pode-se utilizar [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) e [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Veja o exemplo:

```js
const v1 = ["A","B","C"], v2 = [1,2,3], v3 = ["x","y","z"], res = [];

v1.forEach(x=>v2.forEach(y=>v3.forEach(z=>res.push([x,y,z]))));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Teria como deixar "automático" mesmo mudando o numero de arrays?

Comment: @FleuquerLima Da para tornar "automatico" de muitas maneiras dependendo de como está a utilizar no código. Uma das mais diretas seria fazer uma função com este código e chamar essa função sempre que altera os arrays originais.

Answer (score 1):

Um exemplo feio:

```
<?php

  $array1 = array('A', 'B', 'C');
  $array2 = array(1, 2, 3);
  $array3 = array('x', 'y', 'z');

  $output = array();
  foreach ($array1 as $value1) {
    foreach ($array2 as $value2) {
      foreach ($array3 as $value3){
        array_push($output, array($value1, $value2, $value3));
      }
    }
  }

  print_r($output);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu fiz uma versão em JS

```
    var array1 = ["A","B","C"];
    var array2 = [1,2,3];
    var array3 = ["x","y","z"];
    var array4 = [22,33,44];
    var array5 = ["te","s","t"];

    // fazer um array para receber todos os arrays dentro dele
    var conjArray = [array1,array2,array3];
    var tam = conjArray.length;
    var array = [];


    for (var iterable_element1 of array1) {
        for (var iterable_element2 of array2) {
            if (tam == 2) {
                var newarray = [] ;
                newarray.push(iterable_element1);
                newarray.push(iterable_element2);
                array.push(newarray);
            }
            for (var iterable_element3 of array3) {
                if (tam == 3) {
                    var newarray = [] ;
                    newarray.push(iterable_element1);
                    newarray.push(iterable_element2);
                    newarray.push(iterable_element3);
                    array.push(newarray);
                }
                for (var iterable_element4 of array4) {
                    if (tam == 4) {
                        var newarray = [] ;
                        newarray.push(iterable_element1);
                        newarray.push(iterable_element2);
                        newarray.push(iterable_element3);
                        newarray.push(iterable_element4);
                        array.push(newarray);
                    }
                    for (var iterable_element5 of array5) {
                        if (tam == 5) {
                            var newarray = [] ;
                            newarray.push(iterable_element1);
                            newarray.push(iterable_element2);
                            newarray.push(iterable_element3);
                            newarray.push(iterable_element4);
                            newarray.push(iterable_element5);
                            array.push(newarray);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(array);
```

Comment: Teria como deixar "automático" mesmo mudando o numero de arrays?

Comment: @FleuquerLima vou editar minha resposta , ja que vc disse que no minimo de arrays é 2 e o maximo é 5 o melhor que eu consegui foi isso